# Mapping rows to columns in different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am stumped as how to elegantly map data from rows into columns in other tables.

**Input Table**

`FORM_SUBMISSION` Table -

`ID` = The Form Identifier
`ENTRY_ID` = The Question Identifier
`RESPONSE` = Their Response

```
ID  ENTRY_ID   RESPONSE
4   24         John 
4   25         Doe
4   26         Male
4   32         NY
4   30         Life-Threatening
4   30         Other Serious
4   30         Hospitalization
4   28         Tylenol
4   31         I have a headache.
```

I need to map it to a couple tables `PATIENT_INFO`, `PATIENT_OUTCOME`

**Output Tables**

`PATIENT_INFO`

```
REPORT_ID    FIRST_NAME   LAST_NAME    STATE   GENDER    COMPLAINT
4            John         Doe          NY      Male      I have a headache.
```

`PATIENT_OUTCOME`

```
REPORT_ID    OTHER_SERIOUS_IND   LIFE_THREAT_IND    HOSPITAL_IND   DISABILITY_IND
4            Y                   Y                  Y              N
```

So there is no direct way to link the rows to the columns,
Would it be possible to create a mapping based on the `ENTRY_ID` and column name? Though I know for the `IND` columns are based on all rows with `ENTRY_ID` = 30.

Comment: @sstan sorry, I may be misunderstanding, but isn't the desired results what I listed in `PATIENT_INFO` and `PATIENT_OUTCOME`? I am trying to transform source table `FORM_SUBMISSION` to destination tables `PATIENT_INFO` and `PATIENT_OUTCOME`

Comment: @sstan ahh, I edited my post to be more clear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to do with conditional aggregation.  But, in the end, you need still need to figure out the rules to do the mappings correctly.

Here is some sample SQL based on my very basic understanding of how the mapping works. You'll probably need to tweak it further.

**`PATIENT_INFO`**

```
select id as report_id,
       max(case when entry_id = 24 then response end) as first_name,
       max(case when entry_id = 25 then response end) as last_name,
       max(case when entry_id = 32 then response end) as state,
       max(case when entry_id = 26 then response end) as gender,
       max(case when entry_id = 31 then response end) as complaint
  from form_submission
 group by id
```

**`PATIENT_OUTCOME`**

```
select id as report_id,
       nvl(max(case when entry_id = 30 and response = 'Other Serious' then 'Y' end), 'N') as OTHER_SERIOUS_IND,
       nvl(max(case when entry_id = 30 and response = 'Life-Threatening' then 'Y' end), 'N') as LIFE_THREAT_IND,
       nvl(max(case when entry_id = 30 and response = 'Hospitalization' then 'Y' end), 'N') as HOSPITAL_IND,
       nvl(max(case when entry_id = 30 and response = '??Disability??' then 'Y' end), 'N') as DISABILITY_IND
  from form_submission
 group by id
```

Comment: thank you! Is there any way to use a table to do the mapping instead of hard coding it with the entry_id?

Comment: I suppose it's possible to create another table `[entry_id, entry_name]` that you could join on, and then the `case` expressions could check on an `entry_name` instead of a number.  But in my opinion, the part that is a bit *uglier* is how in `patient_outcome` you have to also check against a specific value in `response`.  That seems a bit clunky to me, but I'm not sure you can do much about it.

Comment: @Alan How about making `patient_info` and `patient_outcome` views ?

Comment: @user272735 I am not familiar with views. Could you explain how it would help?

Comment: @Alan A view is a saved query that can be queried as a table. It automatically updates the data changes in underlying table(s). Please see e.g. [tag:sql-view].